# MacVim IM INSERT MODE

Tags: mac, macos, vim, markdown, macvim

While using MacVim to edit markdown files, when I enter the insert (`i`) or append (`a`) mode and type the grave `` ` `` character to start or end a line of code, MacVim switches to `IM INSERT MODE` and sometimes just overwrites the grave `` ` `` character. What is this mode and how can I prevent MacVim from overwriting the grave `` ` `` character?

Comment: I guess that's coming from a plugin. What does `:imap \`` return for you?

Comment: Hm, it returns `No mapping found`. Maybe Max OS X is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` ` `` is a [dead key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) in your active input method (keyboard layout).

`IM INSERT` is MacVim letting you know that you are using a Mac OS X input method mode where your keystrokes will probably be given special interpretation.

You can manage the available input methods in the *Input Sources* tab of the *Language & Text* preference pane in the *System Preferences* application (i.e. the **** > **System Preferences…** menu item). You will probably want to enable *Show Input menu in menu bar* at the bottom to make it easy to switch input methods (and enable the Keyboard Viewer where it is easy to see the dead keys (they are a different color)).